# Specflow not working in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, specflow

I could not get Visual Studio/Specflow integration working. I tried reinstalling Specflow through Nuget Package Manager several times. Still would not highlight feature files or supply any context menu.

I also tried deleting the mapfile that links steps to step definitions.

In the end the solution was much, much simpler. In VS I went to:
Tools >> Extensions and updates >> Installed >> Tools and click on Specflow.

Lo a button that said enable. Click on this and Specflow working again.

I could not find this mentioned anywhere, so reporting it now to hope that someone else can avoid the pain I have been through.

Comment: You might consider moving your fix as an answer. Just make this all easier for visitors to find the help they are looking for and and is consistent with this site (a Q&A site). I found your solution helpful, but could only vote on the question.

Answer (score 2):

All steps required to work with SpecFlow are described in the Getting Started (http://specflow.org/getting-started/) and the documentation (http://specflow.org/documentation/Installation/).

Was there something unclear for you?

Comment: The lead example references Visual Studio 10. That probably throws a few people off, thinking that these pages are possibly very much out of date.

Comment: We mention Visual Studio 2010+. So this version and the later ones. But yes, it's not the clearest writing. We will fix this.